# Devise : overriding the devise routes and controllers at the same time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

i want to ovverride my devise routes and the sessions controller from this gem at the same time. How do i do this ?

I thought about :

```
 devise_for :admins, :skip => [:sessions], 
  controllers: { sessions: "admins/sessions" }

  devise_scope :admin do
    get    'login' => 'devise/sessions#new', :as => :new_admin_session
    post   'login' => 'devise/sessions#create', :as => :admin_session
    delete 'logout' => 'devise/sessions#destroy', :as => :destroy_admin_session
  end
```

but my paths are chaging but the controller - not. How can I implement this right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you specify `controllers: { sessions: "admins/sessions" }`, that implies that you have a file called `sessions_controller.rb` in this path: `app/controllers/admins/sessions_controller.rb`, and that it starts with:

```
module Admins
  class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
```

If this is the controller you want your app to use, then in the `devise_scope` block, you must tell it to use `admins/sessions`, not `devise/sessions`, like this:

```
devise_scope :admin do
  get    'login' => 'admins/sessions#new', :as => :new_admin_session
  post   'login' => 'admins/sessions#create', :as => :admin_session
  delete 'logout' => 'admins/sessions#destroy', :as => :destroy_admin_session
end
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked, but just the second part, i've changed `devise` to `admins`

Answer (score 1):

What about something like:

```
devise_for :admin, exclude: [:sessions] do
   get '/login', to: 'sessions#new', as: :new_admin_session
   post '/login', to: 'sessions#create', as: :admin_session
   delete '/logout', to: 'sessions#destroy', as: :destroy_admin_session
end
```